# Subdomain setup on a Centos server, using BIND and Lighttpd (Vhosts)

Tags: centos, bind, virtualhost

I'm kinda at my wits end here. I'm trying to setup a subdomain on my host on a network.

My computer is ged12345.dev.example.internal on an internal network. This works fine, but I'm trying to setup a plugins subdomain (plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal) to redirect to a directory on the server.

Here's the relevant part of my /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf file:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/lighttpd/plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal/http2"
    server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal/error2.log"
    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal/access2.log"
}

$HTTP["host"] == "ged12345.dev.example.internal" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/lighttpd/plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal/http"
    server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal/error.log"
    accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal/access.log"
}
```

Now, I've confirmed that the bottom host setting works, but the top subdomain does not. Then a friend advised that I might needed to setup Bind to get the name resolution correct. Now, the nameserver on the network that I no control over. As far as I can tell, I can still use bind to properly resolve to my plugin subdomain. I assume the request goes to the namesever, then gets forwarded to Bind to resolve the address, but when I use nslookup I can't find plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal.

Do I need Bind? Or does this host setting (basically a virtual host) take care of it all? Any help or guidance you could offer me would be amazing because I'm very lost.

Here is my named.conf:

```
options {
       listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 10.2.3.205;};
       #       listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
       directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { any; };
    #recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
 managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "ged12345.dev.example.internal" IN {
        type master;
        file "ged12345.dev.example.internal.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "6.2.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "ged12345.dev.example.internal.revzone";
        allow-update { none; };
};


include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Here is my zone file (ged12345.dev.example.internal.one)

```
TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     vip-dns.prod.example.internal. ged12345.dev.example.internal. (
        2013042207  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
; Specify our two nameservers
                IN      NS              vip-dns.prod.example.internal.
vip-dns         IN      A               10.3.2.205
; Define hostname -> IP pairs which you wish to resolve
client          IN      A               10.2.6.52
www             IN      CNAME           client
plugins         IN      CNAME           client
```

Here is my reverse zone file (ged12345.dev.example.internal.revzone):

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     vip-dns.prod.example.internal. ged12345.dev.example.internal. (
        3013042211  ;Serial
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

@                IN      NS             vip-dns.prod.example.internal.
; Define hostname -> IP pairs which you wish to resolve
52              IN      PTR             ged12345.dev.example.internal.
205             IN      PTR             vip-dns.prod.example.internal.
52              IN      PTR             plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal.
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get in the browser ?

Comment: `My computer is ged12345.dev.example.internal` ...and thus, the society for the prevention of cruelty to computers (SPCC) was born.

Comment: Iain, I get a 'THis webpage is not available' message.

Comment: Actually, Iain, this is the sub-message: 
'The server at plugins.ged12345.dev.example.internal can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed.'

Comment: So it's actually a DNS issue, nothing to do with lighttpd. Is the BIND-configured DNS-Server in use? Isn't an entry in the hosts file enough?

Comment: hosts file is probably the easiest solution. To override DNS you need to use (/etc/resolv.conf) and run your own DNS resolver, which forwards normal request to the "real DNS", and overrides custom zones. Or just ask your sysadmin to add an alias for your machine.